# SQL Unclosed quotation error in PowerShell

Tags: sql-server, powershell, azure-powershell, powershell-4.0, powershell-remoting

I have a small PowerShell Script that uploads CSV files to my SQL Server database using the `Invoke-Sqlcmd` command. It's working fine if the CSV file is small but I'm getting this error if the file has over 10,000 records.

> Unclosed quotation mark after the character string.

I though the error is something else but it weird that it's working fine if I test with smaller size csv file.

```
    $CSVImport = Import-CSV $PNP_CSV
    ForEach ($CSVLine in $CSVImport) {
        $CSVItemID = $CSVLine.ItemId
        $CSVItemPath = $CSVLine.Path

      
        $query = "USE $Global:Database
            INSERT INTO PNP_Main (ItemId, ItemPath)
            VALUES('$CSVItemID', '$CSVItemPath');"
        Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query $query -ServerInstance $Global:Server -Database $Global:Database

    }
```

Any help or suggestion would be really appreciated.

Comment: One of your `ItemId` or `Path` values probably contains an `'` character. This is why [SQL injection is bad](https://xkcd.com/327/) and why you should use parameterized queries instead of inlining tainted user data into your SQL query strings.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning could you help me how can I fix it in my PowerShell?

Comment: You can try escaping any single quotes in your values by doing a replace on each of the variables.  `VALUES('$($CSVItemID -replace "'", "''")', $($CSVItemPath -replace "'", "''")');"`